# modifying elements in string array located in list while iterating with for loop c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

So i've got a school project called the blog, the user saves post in a string array that is kept in a list. I want the user to have the option to edit a previous post. I've got the editing part to work but my loop doesnt iterate through all the elements located in the list, instead it goes from the first element to the last element saved in the list when the user tries to access the "next" element. I've tried alot of stuff that didn't work so thanful for any type of help

```cs
void Redigera()
{
  foreach (string[] edit in minBlogg) //each array has 3 elements in it
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < minBlogg.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(minBlogg[i][i]);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");


        Console.WriteLine("[1]. Redigera");
        Console.WriteLine("[2]. Nästa inlägg");
        Console.WriteLine("[3]. Återgå till Huvudmeny");


        string ettTvå = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        switch (ettTvå)          
        {
            case "1":
                Console.Write("Redigera titel: ");
                minBlogg[i][i] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Redigera inlägg: ");
                minBlogg[i][1] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ditt inlägg har sparats!");
                break;

            case "2":   //so if the user presses 2 I want to access the next element
                continue; //but instead it skips to the "last" element in the list



            case "3":
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.ReadKey();
                break;

        }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: The edit variable of the first foreach is used nowhere. The first 2 loops actually iterate over the same thing and i don't know what `minBlogg[i][i]` should be good for? Changing both dimensions here seems wrong. I assume you are missing on debugging capabilities to understand your own code. That something you should do first learn how to debug.

Comment: Typically with a nested loop (in your case it sounds like it's a `List<string[]>`?) you would do something like: `for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < minBlogg.Count; listIndex++) { for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < minBlogg[listIndex].Length; arrayIndex++) { var arrayItem = minBlogg[listIndex][arrayIndex]; } }` Does that help at all? It's not clear from your code exactly what you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what your list of arrays represents, but I can show you the typical way you might edit an item in an array that's contained in a list:

```
// minBlogg = List<string[]>


for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < minBlogg.Count; listIndex++) 
{ 
    for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < minBlogg[listIndex].Length; arrayIndex++)
    { 
        // retrieve the current item
        var arrayItem = minBlogg[listIndex][arrayIndex]; 

        // edit the current item
        minBlogg[listIndex][arrayIndex] = "New value";
    } 
}
```